# Passing coordinates stored in Semantic MediaWiki subobject to Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I'd like to pass multiple sets of coordinates from different subobject fields into maps. I have tried storing the coordinates in separate property values and calling them  like so:

```
<div class="LeafletPageMap">{{#ask:[[{{PAGENAME}}]] 
|?Has categorya coordinates
|?Has categoryb coordinates}}</div>
```

Which works fine, but I'd like to take advantage of the subobjects' ability to hold larger sets of relations-- especially for calls on other pages. I'd like to get a something with the following to work:

```
{{#subobject:
|locationtidbit= an unexpected tidbit to consider|+sep=;
|locationdescription=Another spot to consider|+sep=;
|locationcoordinates= -45.67805, -38.9820|+sep=;
|locationnotes=a baby subsidiary co.|+sep=;
|@category=geo, location
}}
{{#subobject:
|locationdescription=lorem blah ipsum blah|+sep=;
|locationcoordinates= -74.67805, -103.9820|+sep=;
|locationnotes=afdsdsddfo|+sep=;
|@category=geo, location
}}
{{#subobject:
|locationdescription=less important description|+sep=;
|locationcoordinates= -75.647805, -74.9820|+sep=;
|locationnotes=|+sep=;
|@category=geo, location
}}
{{#subobject:
|locationtidbit= an predictable tidbit to consider|+sep=;
|locationdescription=very important location description |+sep=;
|locationcoordinates= -35.67805, -65.9820|+sep=;
|locationnotes=a bakjh sdkjh sdkjh sd co.|+sep=;
|@category=geo, location
}}
```

and then call with:

```
{{#display_map: {{#ask: [[-Has subobject::{{PAGENAME}}]][[Category:geo, location]] 
 |?locationcoordinates #
 |mainlabel=-
 |headers=hide
 |format=plainlist
 |sep=&thinsp;;&thinsp;
}}}}
```

I have been able to get both the first and last set of coordinates to show respectively, but never the whole group. The above code plots the last set, and if I rename the subobjects to

```
{{#subobject:1... {{#subobject:2... {{#subobject:3... {{#subobject:4...
```

for example, the first coordinate will be plotted. Really want to get the whole group and to incorporate subobject groups yet to be realized!

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `ask` query with:

```
{{#ask: [[-Has subobject::{{FULLPAGENAME}}]][[Category:geo, location]] 
 |?locationcoordinates #
 |mainlabel=-
 |headers=hide
 |format=plainlist
 |sep=;
}}
```

1. `{{PAGENAME}}` will not work correctly outside of the main namespace.
2. Coordinates for `{{#displaymap:}}` should be separated with `;`, no fancy thin spaces.

Also consider not querying the page itself but passing the coordinates from template or module parametres directly.